# How to add transition background to buttons when visiting from One webpage to another depending on which webpage you came from?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

I have a design Idea to implement in navigation buttons in which **When the user clicks any other button** the background of **the current button**, say "HOME" *transition* to the button the *user clicked*, **when the webpage the user selected is loaded**, **WHILE** simultaneously changing the font color of the button text.

Below is an image which will give you want I want to do. Any idea or any website you have sen this working will work. The font color is exactly what I want to transition.
Thanking you in advance.

[How it should look  on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA11z.png)

Comment: I found the solution for your question. Example code/demo [here](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/bVQZvy). Tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/creating-an-animated-menu-indicator-with-css-selectors/). Hope I was helpful again :)

Comment: And as other answer suggest, you must use javascript for this, maybe an async loader when the user click on the menu.

Comment: Well although it looks good, it isn't doing what I actually wanted. The transition should to be performed once the user visits the link, **and then the slider should move from its parent/initial indicating website to visited one**. i.e.  remembering where it came from

Comment: Well change some js that remember the start page/menu position :)

Comment: Okay! well I try my level best to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use ajax to implement this as it will only be possible in an SPA. An application that refreshes would defeat the use of transitions. I cant write the code for you but will be able to help you if you have a code sample u have tried

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know either of these things. Neither do I know Javascript.. Anyway thanks for the info

Comment: u will need javascript in this

Comment: hey visit the [website](https://anurag-117.github.io/) for which I want this feature.

Comment: what library are u using for this website

Comment: It uses an open source library for animation. Except that everything is in Css.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse u will need JS for this