# How to change Multiple small-res image source with the actual high-res image after they have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm working on a webpage that **loads high-resolution images after low-res images are applied** and set them to the initially loaded small low-res images. This is done to **load smaller blurred images faster** and **replace them with high-res images**, *unblurred* after they have been **loaded completely**.

I'm trying javascript to add this functionality but got stuck. Particularly because I'm new to this. This is what I wrote so far. Any help is appreciated. T

```js
(function() {
  let image = document.images //all low-res blurred images of class "image"
  let big_image = document.getElementsByClassName("image")

  function loadImage() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= big_image.length; i++) {
      big_image.onload = function() {
        image[i].src = big_image[i].src
        image[i].className = "noBlur" //set class to noblur from image to remove the blur filter
      }
    }
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    big_image[0].src = "mainPage/res/fireWatch.jpg" //actual high res image srcs
    big_image[1].src = "mainPage/res/mountainMan.jpg"
    big_image[2].src = "mainPage/res/pyramid.jpg"
    big_image[3].src = "mainPage/res/valley.jpg"
    big_image[4].src = "mainPage/res/valley.jpg"
    big_image[5].src = "mainPage/res/valley.jpg"
  }, 50)
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadImage, false);
}());
```

[inspiration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMteSxT5uGM&t=100s)

Comment: What you are looking for is called **Progressive Image Loading** and you can see It browsing [Medium](https://medium.com) website. You can follow this guides ti obtain the same "effect": [First](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/progressive-image-loading-and-intersectionobserver-d0359b5d90cd) | [Second](https://medium.com/frontend-digest/progressively-loading-images-in-react-107cb075417a) | [Third](https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/)

Comment: You could try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4jsp935L/

Comment: Thankyou, @CarloCorradini, I worked on both of your suggestions but ended up using an open-source library. For sure you helped in acquiring more information about this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment suggests, Progressive image loading like [medium](https://medium.com/) can be implemented by using a simple open-source files from GitHub [**blurry-image-load**](https://github.com/dombrant/blurry-image-load). Read readme.md and add the necessary files to your project and follow the instruction.

Comment: I suggest you to use a more robust library such as [vanilla-lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload) and apply a blur filter to every unloaded image.

Comment: @CarloCorradini Thanks for one more suggestion. I'll try this one also. If you are interested you can help me solve me one more [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62670221/8277795)

Comment: Done, hope I was helpful again :)